# Why can I change the type of dictionary values inside the loop but its failing when I check

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, type-conversion, try-catch

I have a dictionary of mixed value types: floats, int and string. When I first open and read the values are are all strings and I need to change them to the appropriate type. I made a for/try loop that seemed to work, the print statements inside the loop show that the value have changed. But when I double checked I saw they were all still strings? I cant seem to figure out whats going wrong.

Data:

```
>>> racoondict
{'Year': ['2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008', '2008'], 'Day': ['6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008', '6/19/2008'], 'Time': ['6:00 AM', '7:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '8:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '9:00 AM', '10:00 AM', '11:00 AM', '11:00 AM', '12:00 PM', '1:00 PM', '2:00 PM', '3:00 PM', '4:00 PM'], 'George #': ['6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6'], ' X': ['591071.374756626', '591112.752918467', '591159.738875885', '591177.048458523', '591184.067274814', '591192.036321619', '591210.13894318', '591257.350537335', '591307.574400613', '591303.184361127', '591243.186822335', '591183.256748391', '591123.432415996', '591121.339525596'], ' Y': ['4504664.29938361', '4504620.85001397', '4504583.53621216', '4504546.70960308', '4504531.77688002', '4504547.28129659', '4504582.5013916', '4504619.52929159', '4504641.73534564', '4504639.79432702', '4504639.25087614', '4504636.35497609', '4504631.76702955', '4504571.80354225'], ' Asleep': ['False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'False'], 'Behavior Mode': ['SafeSearchModifier', 'RiskySearchModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier', 'RiskyForageModifier'], 'Energy Level': ['1000', '887.8', '777.8', '704.1', '687.6', '770.6', '698', '588', '486.8', '478', '368', '258', '148', '37.9999999999999'], 'Risk': ['0.00192', '0.002', '0.00134', '0.000165', '0.00017', '0.00132', '0.002', '0.00184', '0.00016', '0.002', '0.002', '0.002', '0.002', '0.00078'], 'ProbFoodCap': ['0.045', '0.1', '0.067', '0.33', '0.34', '0.066', '0.1', '0.092', '0.008', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1', '0.1', '0.039'], 'MVL': ['0.715', '0.65', '0.65', '0.3', '0.3', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65', '0.65'], 'MSL': ['60', '60', '40.2', '16.5', '17', '39.6', '60', '55.2', '4.8', '60', '60', '60', '60', '23.4'], 'PercptionDist': ['50.5', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50', '50'], 'Percent Step': ['1', '1', '0.67', '0.33', '0.34', '0.66', '1', '0.92', '0.08', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0.39']}
```

Loop:

```
for key, value in racoondict.items():
    try:
        for value in racoondict[key]:
            value = float(value)
            if value.is_integer():
                value = int(value)
            print(type(value), value)
    except ValueError:
        print(type(value), value)
        pass
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'int'> 2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6:00 AM
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'int'> 6
<class 'float'> 591071.374756626
<class 'float'> 591112.752918467
<class 'float'> 591159.738875885
<class 'float'> 591177.048458523
<class 'float'> 591184.067274814
<class 'float'> 591192.036321619
<class 'float'> 591210.13894318
<class 'float'> 591257.350537335
<class 'float'> 591307.574400613
<class 'float'> 591303.184361127
etc
```

Check:

```
for key, value in racoondict.items():
    for value in racoondict[key]:
        print (type(value),value)

<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6/19/2008
<class 'str'> 6:00 AM
<class 'str'> 7:00 AM
<class 'str'> 8:00 AM
<class 'str'> 8:00 AM
<class 'str'> 9:00 AM
<class 'str'> 9:00 AM
<class 'str'> 10:00 AM
<class 'str'> 11:00 AM
<class 'str'> 11:00 AM
<class 'str'> 12:00 PM
<class 'str'> 1:00 PM
<class 'str'> 2:00 PM
<class 'str'> 3:00 PM
<class 'str'> 4:00 PM
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 6
<class 'str'> 591071.374756626
<class 'str'> 591112.752918467
<class 'str'> 591159.738875885
<class 'str'> 591177.048458523
<class 'str'> 591184.067274814
<class 'str'> 591192.036321619
<class 'str'> 591210.13894318
<class 'str'> 591257.350537335
<class 'str'> 591307.574400613
<class 'str'> 591303.184361127
etc
```

Comment: `value = float(value)` does _not_ change the dictionary; here, `value` is _not_ something like a pointer to the object you have in mind.

Comment: Could you expand? I basically just altered this [code](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/convert+dict+values+to+int+python)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Thank you your comment helped:

```
for key, value in racoondict.items():
    try:
        for value in racoondict[key]:
            if float(value).is_integer():
                racoondict[key][racoondict[key].index(value)] = int(value)
            else:
                racoondict[key][racoondict[key].index(value)] = float(value)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: as another trick also, if know of `pandas` library can make use of pandas datatype conversion (some tips in [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/converting-data-to-a-numeric-type-in-pandas-db9415caab0b)) and if need dataframe back to dictionary in similar orientation as you had originally, can use `df.to_dict(orient='list')`

Comment: It's for an assignment and we're not allowed to use pandas :/